# Can any ebook be stored and read on the ereader for 'The Hitchhiker's Guide To The Galaxy'?

Tags: the-hitchhikers-guide-to-the-galaxy

['The Hitchhiker's Guide To The Galaxy'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy_%28fictional%29) is both an ebook and an reader [see related question](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/968). Is the relationship necessarily one to one? Can the ebook be stored and read on a different ereader?  Can the ereader store and display other ebooks?

Looking for in universe, canon supported answer.  If there is a difference in  franchises of the universe please indicate.

Comment: @JamesJenkins: I don’t see anything in that question indicating that The Guide is both an ebook and a reader, in the sense that we’d understand them. Could you provide a little supporting evidence for that assertion?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - in-universe, it is.  The OP is referring to *The Guide* (i.e the electronic book with "Don't Panic" printed on it's case, published by Megadodo Publications of Ursa Minor Beta) which is described in terms we'd understand as being an e-book today.  However, since the modern concept of e-books didn't even exist when the stories were written this may be difficult to answer.

Comment: @JimmyShelter: oh, I know that's what the OP's referring to. I just wasn't sure the e-book-plus-e-reader description was justified (like @EdCottrell), although it has been some years since I've read the book.

Comment: I don't see the Guide as an e-reader. More like a tablet.

Comment: The Guide is literally referred to as "a sort of electronic book".  In the earlier adaptations, and the first couple of books, it appears to be a static physical device, with new editions sold as new physical devices.  It's in (IIRC) SLATFATF that the book is first described as having a download function, with updates beamed through the sub-ether to the device.  This is most likely because such technology didn't exist when Adams wrote the first versions, and it didn't cross his mind to invent it.

Comment: Randall Munroe has suggested the opposite: that e-readers are in fact the Hitchhiker's Guide in disguise. https://m.xkcd.com/548/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, as you no doubt recall, [The Guide Mark II](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_minor_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy_characters#Guide_Mark_II) (introduced in [*Mostly Harmless*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Mostly_Harmless)) was a Vogon-engineered, bird-like, multi-dimensional, time-traveling WMD. If it is considered a legitimate version of the Guide, then no, the Guide was far more than an ebook/ereader. Trying to read it on your Kindle might prompt the Guide Mark II to turn your device into sentient radioactive slag that would kill your great-great-grandparents whilst simultaneously taunting your great-great-grandchildren, just for sport.

Even in the "Mark I" sense, I think the Guide was more like a combination of an iPad, Wikipedia, and Stack Exchange - evolving, dynamic, non-linear, and subject to various kinds of abuse.

So, my vote is: no, the Guide is neither ereader nor ebook, and trying to use it simply as either might cause justified panicking.

Comment: "Guide Mark II to turn your device into sentient radioactive slag that would kill your great-great-grandparents whilst simultaneously taunting your great-great-grandchildren, just for sport"....I think you have captured the very essence of Douglas Adams in that quote.